# Ajax upload script + file type filtering

Tags: php, html, upload

I have an ajax upload script which i will post below. It will upload any file with any extention. I want it to only upload .png files but i dont know how to do that.

Here are my files:

```
<h1>Ajax File Upload Demo</h1>

<form id="myForm" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Name it: 
<input type="text" name="upload_name">

<br>
     <input type="file" size="60" name="myfile">
     <input type="submit" value="Ajax File Upload">
 </form>

 <div id="progress">
        <div id="bar"></div>
        <div id="percent">0%</div >
</div>
<br/>

<div id="message"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var options = { 
    beforeSend: function() 
    {
        $("#progress").show();
        //clear everything
        $("#bar").width('0%');
        $("#message").html("");
        $("#percent").html("0%");
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) 
    {
        $("#bar").width(percentComplete+'%');
        $("#percent").html(percentComplete+'%');

    },
    success: function() 
    {
        $("#bar").width('100%');
        $("#percent").html('100%');

    },
    complete: function(response) 
    {
        $("#message").html("<font color='green'>"+response.responseText+"</font>");
    },
    error: function()
    {
        $("#message").html("<font color='red'> ERROR: unable to upload files</font>");

    }

}; 

     $("#myForm").ajaxForm(options);

});

</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$upload_name = $_POST['upload_name'];

$idx = strpos($_FILES['myfile']['name'],'.');
$ext = substr($_FILES['myfile']['name'],$idx);

$file_name = $upload_name . $ext;

$output_dir = "uploads/";

if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))

{
    //Filter the file types , if you want.

    if ($_FILES["myfile"]["error"] > 0)

    {
      echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";

    }
    else
    {
        //move the uploaded file to uploads folder;

//        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);

//     echo "Uploaded File :".$_FILES["myfile"]["name"];


 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$file_name);

 echo "Uploaded File :" . $file_name;

    }

}
?>
```

Sorry, i'm new and code blocks wont work for me. If someone could update, that would be great.

Comment: You'll have to check the mime type of your upploaded file with `$_FILES["myfile"]["type"]` and see if it is equal to `image/png`.

Answer (score 0):

**Client side**

change your input file field **this only works for modern browsers** IE10+
Google Chrome 8.0+ and Firefox 4.0+

```
  <input type="file" size="60" name="myfile" accept="image/png" />
```

**PHP**

```
   $ext = pathinfo( $file_name , PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

   if(strtolower($ext) == 'png' && $_FILES["file"]['type'] == "image/png")
   {
       // upload file
   } else{
      // not allowed
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check file extension or mime type at server side.

```
// check extension
$info = new SplFileInfo($_FILES['myfile']['name']);
if ($info->getExtension() !== 'png') {
    // return error
}

// or check file mime type
if (mime_content_type($_FILES['myfile']['name']) !== 'image/png') {
    // return error
}
```

Example php:

```
$output_dir = "uploads/";
$upload_name = $_POST['upload_name'];

if(isset($_FILES["myfile"])) {
    // Check upload errors
    if ($_FILES["myfile"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        return;
    }

    // Check extensions
    $info = new SplFileInfo($_FILES['myfile']['name']);
    if ($info->getExtension() !== 'png') {
        echo "Error: Only .png files are allowed";
        return;
    }

    // Upload file
    $file_name = $upload_name . $info->getExtension();
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"], $output_dir . $file_name);
    echo "Uploaded File :" . $file_name;
}
```

Comment: Im not sure how i would include that to give me an error when i upload another file with a different extention.  Could you please put them together? Thanks.